# Progress bar too fast

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

The progress bar first tracks the copying of files, then the updating of their contents. For some reason the progress bar hits 100% the second time way before the files have all been updated.

```
Private Sub cmdGenerate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdGenerate.Click
    Dim CatalogFiles As String() = IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirCatalogues & "\" & cboCatalog.Text, "*"),
        NewFile As String,
        cnt As Integer = 0
    prg.Visible = True
    lblProgress.Visible = True
    Dim dwgs As String() = IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirNewProject, "*.dwg")
    prg.Minimum = 0
    prg.Maximum = dwgs.Length
    prg.Value = 0
    lblProgress.Text = "Updating drawings:"
    For Each dwg In dwgs
        CAD.FindReplace(dwg, strNomenclatureFind, strNomenclatureReplace)
        CAD.FindReplace(dwg, strProjectNameFind, strProjectNameReplace)
        cnt = cnt + 1
        prg.Increment(cnt)
    Next
    MsgBox("Done.")
    ResetForm()
End Sub
```

Comment: rather than `Increment(1)` to indicate a step of 1, you are incrementing progressively with `prg.Increment(cnt)`.  On the thrid one, you will be increasing it by 6 (1+2+3) for a single item. Also make sure `cnt` is starting at 1 if you even need it

Comment: I failed to post all of my code, yet your solution holds.  Thank you!

Comment: `prg.PerformStep()`  Make sure the ProgressBar's Step property is set to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `prg.Increment(cnt)`, replace it with `prog.Increment(1)` since Increment is:

> *The amount by which to increment the progress bar's current position.*

Or replace it with `prg.Value(cnt)` since Value is:

> *Gets or sets the current position of the progress bar.*

References:

- [Progress Bar Increment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.increment(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Progress Bar Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.value(v=vs.110).aspx)